# What is this issue of variable affectation in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have this problem in python. I have a function which take the following inputs

```
import numpy;
from numpy import *;
def GetInf(G, X, m, n):
    g           = G[m - 1, :].T;
    Y           = X;
    Y[m - 1, :] = 0;
    Y[:, n - 1] = 0;
    # Here I modify Y. The problem is that X is modified too. Why?
    # In fact, I add Y after I see that X is changing but X keeps changing.
    result      =  sum(Y * G);
    return result;

G = array([[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.]]);
X = array([[1., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 1.]]);
I = GetInf(G, X, 1, 1);
```

My problem is that when I debug the program I see that after modifying `Y`, `X` is also modified. I cannot understand why.

Comment: `Y` and `X` are names that point to the same object, if you want a copy do: `Y = X.copy()`.

Comment: you are assigning X to the Y variable. it is not the same as copying the matrix, but assigning the matrix object itself. so altering x is the same as altering y. try calling `Y = x.copy()`

Comment: Here is a blog post explaining how variable assignment works in python. http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/

Comment: Off-topic, but affectation doesn't mean what you think it does: *behaviour, speech, or writing that is pretentious and designed to impress.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it because of that you assign `X` to `Y` . that means `Y` is a reference to where `X` refer ! if you don't want that you have to make a copy of `X` :

```
Y=np.copy(X)
```